# Settings for multiple instances in VB

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Which is the best way to store application and user settings of an application running with multiple instances?

My problem is that using the vb's "Application Settings" one instance would overwrite the other one.

I want to identify each instance with a number passed via command line argument. I could use this number to identify the appropriate settings of the running instance, but I see in a local INI o XML file a better way to handle that.

Is there any alternative, maybe native in .NET?

Thank you.

Comment: Manually passing a number on the command line to uniquely identify each instance is probably not going to work very well.  It is tedious at best, and probably error prone.  Unless you have a way to automate this, where the user doesn't even have to know such a number exists (such as a tool to create shortcuts for them), then I'd recommend you come up with a different strategy for that part.

Comment: You are right: passing the device number as argument in a shortcut is not the best way, but till now I did not find any better way.
Of course, I created a user friendly tool to generate shortcuts with the right device number, but I never had a good feeling for that solution.
Other solution would have been a single program, working as launcher, where the user would choose the device to start (and so I could launch the main program instance with the right device number).
But the user already told me that they would be bored by this one more click... they prefer the shortcut-one-click solution!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best idea for this scenario is to use a database.  Concurrent access is what databases are designed for.  It will be simpler to develop and maintain than most custom cross-process data storage solutions.

Maybe [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) (since it is well-integrated into VS), or SQL Server Express.

You could also try a DB that is a bit more embedded, and simpler to install/distribute, like [SqLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).  Here are a couple quick tutorials on how to get started with SqLite:

- http://web.archive.org/web/20100208133236/http://www.mikeduncan.com/sqlite-on-dotnet-in-3-mins/ (mostly goes over installation, and what classes you'll use)
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SQLiteCSharp.aspx (starts to mention query syntax)

Comment: yes, the db is a good idea, especially in a network where the user can start its own instance on different machines: the program could retrieve all settings from a central DB. I like the idea, but I cannot use in my actual application: it is a mission critical program and must run even if the network fails.

I have to think about storing the settings in a local embedded db vs ini/xml files: I have more experience with the second solution, never thought that could use a db, also because it looks like something heavy vs an ini files.

Comment: @gingo: It's about a meg for the 32 bit version.  This includes both the main DLL (~750k) and Linq features (~150k).  Because it's embedded, it's supposed to be very fast - much more so than standard DB access.  It's also [not the only game in town](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database).  But it sounds like you'd probably figure that out, if you hadn't already :)

Comment: I will try sqlite, but I would prefer something included in .NET (like SQL Server Compact) without adding a new ddl wrapper. I can not figure out how to manage all upgrades of the sqlite engine, but on the other hand, if my application works with the current version of the sqlite-engine, it should be no reason to update the dll if any new version would come.
Moreover, how to manage the multiaccess from the different instances? "SQLite is multitasking concerning reads. Writes can be done only one-at-a-time."

Comment: @gingo: Check the FAQ: [Can multiple applications or multiple instances of the same application access a single database file at the same time?](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5) - "When any process wants to write, it must lock the entire database file for the duration of its update ... Other embedded SQL database engines typically only allow a single process to connect to the database at once."  Also: "...experience suggests that most applications need much less concurrency than their designers imagine".  I believe they mean read/write concurrency... Read concurrency is already stellar.